# Tips for calling WSE service from WCF?

Tags: wcf, wse

I've got a WSE 3.0 web service that I'm trying to call using a VS 2008-generated WCF client.  VS generated the client with a basicHttpBinding but I'm getting the exception "Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.SecurityFault: Security requirements are not satisfied because the security header is not present in the incoming message."

I'm assuming this is caused by a missing WSE header or configuration item but I can't find any docs on calling WSE from WCF and no description of how to change my WCF client configuration to work in this case.

Is there some good source for finding information about how to get WCF to WSE calls to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the WSE / WCF Integration:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734745.aspx

Comment: I've read throught this example and it does help but doesn't give a real explanation of what configuration item in WCF corresponds to different WSE implementations.

I'm really looking for a guide that gives documentation on what corresponds to what in WSE and WCf vs. sample code.

I'm going to upvote this answer because it does help but I don't think I'm going to accept it as the definitive answer just yet.

Comment: This link doesn't really give a definitive list of the WSE 3.0 to WCF configuration correspondence, it appears to be the best that's available at this date.
If in the future your get to this question and you've found more complete documentation, please note the link as an answer to this question.